# Getting relations with Association Object right

Tags: sqlalchemy, scrapy

When scraping a website using Scrapy, to create a database of the following form (as defined in models.py in the tutorial structure):

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Table, ForeignKey, MetaData
    from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy import (Integer, String, Date, DateTime, Float, Boolean, Text)
    from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
    
    Base = declarative_base()
    
    def db_connect():
        return create_engine(get_project_settings().get("CONNECTION_STRING"))
    
    def create_table(engine):
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    Article_author = Table('article_author', Base.metadata,
      Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('article.article_id'), primary_key=True),
      Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('author.author_id'), primary_key=True),
      Column('author_number', Integer)
    )

    class Article(Base):
      __tablename__ = "article"

      article_id    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      article_title = Column('name', String(50), unique=True)
      authors = relationship('Author', secondary='article_author',lazy='dynamic', backref="article") 

    class Author(Base):
      __tablename__ = "author"

      author_id        = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      author_name     = Column('name', String(50), unique=True)
      articles = relationship('Article', secondary='article_author',lazy='dynamic', backref="article")
```

an error occurs when adding an author number (e.g. first or second author) to the automatically created association table 'article_author' as I don't know how to acces the table from the pipelines.py script.
There is a many-to-many relation between article and author tables as an author can write multiple articles and articles can have multiple authors. The article table has a unique article_id and the author table has a unique author_id. The association table has a unique (article_id,author_id) structure.
In the pipeline.py script there is a function proces_item in which an instance of articles can be made, after which the author and association tables are updated accordingly. The question is how the author number can be inserted as well.

Is there a relation that should be added in models.py?

The script pipeline.py reads:

```
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
    from tutorial.models import Article, Author, Article_author, Article_author, db_connect, create_table
    
    class SavePipeline(object):
        
        def __init__(self):
            """
            Initializes database connection and sessionmaker
            Creates tables
            """
            engine = db_connect()
            create_table(engine)
            self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    
    
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            session = self.Session()
            article = Article()
            #article_author = Article_author()
    
            #check whether the current article has authors or not
            if 'author' in item:
                for author,n in zip(item["author"],item["n"]):
                    writer = Author(author=author)
                    # check whether author already exists in the database
                    exist = session.query(Author).filter_by(author = writer.author).first()
                    if exist_title is not None:  
                    # the current author exists
                        writer = exist
                    article.authors.append(writer)
                    nr = article_author(author_number =n)
                    article.article_author.append(nr)
                    #article_author.append(nr)
                    #article.authors.append(pag) 
                    #article_author.author_number = n               
    
            try:
                session.add(proverb)
                session.commit()
    
            except:
                session.rollback()
                raise
    
            finally:
                session.close()
    
            return item
```

The resulting error from the terminal is an integrity error as it cannot be related to the author_id:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: article_author.author_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO proverb_source (article_id, author_number) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (30, 2]
```

When defining an instance Article_author in process_item and appending it via

```
    nr = Article_author(author_number =n)
    article_author.append(nr)
```

it results in an attribute error:

```
article_author.append(nr)
AttributeError: 'Article_author' object has no attribute 'append'
```

When adding it via the authors member of article

```
    article.authors.append(pag)
```

it gives a ValueError:

```
ValueError: Bidirectional attribute conflict detected: Passing object <Article_author at 0x7f9007276c70> to attribute "Article.authors" triggers a modify event on attribute "Article.article_author" via the backref "Article_author.article".
```

When accessing it directly it gives no error, but leaves the column empty,

```
article_author.author_number = n
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb, thank you for the response, I added the error traceback. Maybe  it can be solved by accessing it as a member of article: article.article_authors, but this probably needs to be defined in a relation. Do you perhaps know how?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, thank you for the response, I added the '''process_item''', I forgot to import the association table class. Now it gives an integrity error. Do you know how to call the right way?

Comment: Instead of nr = article_author(author_number =n)
article.article_author.append(nr)

Comment: Writing the association table with a capital gives an InvalidRequestError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by defining the relations from the association table and appending from this table, cf.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/glossary.html#term-association-relationship